# Permission denied to git push as a contributor

Tags: github, git-push

Recently I have been added as a contributor to a program allowing me to make some changes but I can't git push my fixed code to the repo.

---

The error is as follows:

remote: Permission denied to myusername.

fatal: unable to access 'program URL': The requested URL returned error: 403

---

I can create a pull request to modify the file but my instructor said it would be troublesome if he had to check the request and merge them every time so he added me as a contributor.

I googled my question and some said I need to add my SSH key to my instructor's account, but does it mean I have permissions to all repo of my instructor?

I'm just a beginner in github, many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an SSH key for your own account (not your instructor's). If he added you as a contributor and you cloned the repository via SSH (as it seems you did), Github will check your personal SSH key to identify you whenever you try to push.

Just follow these steps to add your SSH key to your account: https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account

Comment: I removed my old SSH key and regenerated it following the instruction, but it still does not work..

Comment: setsockopt IPV6_TCLASS 8: Operation not permitted:
ERROR: Permission denied. 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: Have you cloned the repo via HTTPS or SSH? The latter is preferred. You can always remove origin and add it again without losing your local changes (`git remote rm origin` + `git remote add origin <ssh-url-to-repo>`).

Comment: Also are you using Windows? That error seems to be related to IPV6_TCLASS not being supported in Windows. Cygwin worked that around but other tools might still fail with that.

Comment: yea I cloned the repo via SSH and my remote origin is in SSH form not HTTPS one. I'm using WSL, it seems ipv6 is not supported on the system... I'm gonna try it again on my Mac. Many thanks for your help !